# Limits of sequence Riemann sums

Tags: limits, riemann-integration

I'm trying to calculate the limit by interpreting the limit as a sequence of Riemann sums that converges to the Riemann integral:

$$
\lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n
\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+2kn}}
$$

I have:

$$
\lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^{2}+2kn}} = \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2kn}{n^{2}}}}
$$

but don't know how to get to the integral and compute the limit. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You should write:

$$ \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2kn}{n^{2}}}}= \lim\limits_{n \to + \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum\limits_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2\frac{k}{n}}}$$

Do you see the integral now? It is:

> $$\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+2x}}\,dx$$

Comment: Thanks Atticus - what's the intuition behind the final step?

Comment: @matthew, when you write a Riemann sum, you want to factor 1/n in front of the sum and write the summand as a function of k/n.